# Jquery .after()

Tags: jquery

O erro no código é que, quando clico no botão "Adicionar" novo input file, a intenção é adicionar apenas um campo após o último, mas o botão triplica.

Meu código HTML está assim:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="form-group input-files">
    <input type="file" name="imagem_file[]" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group input-files">
    <input type="file" name="imagem_file[]" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group input-files">
    <input type="file" name="imagem_file[]" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

E o botão para a ação:

```
<button onClick="addInput();" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">[+]</button>
```

O javascript está assim:

```
<script>
function addInput(){
    $(".input-files").after('<div class="form-group input-files"><input type="file" name="imagem_file[]" class="form-control"></div>');
}
</script>
```

Se deixar apenas um campo input file, ele gera outro, mas a partir daí ele vai multiplicando pela quantidade que está sendo gerada.

O exemplo no [Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BryvQj).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seletor `".input-files"` acerta em 3 `<div class="input-files">` do seu html original, por esse motivo acrescenta um novo elemento a seguir a cada um. Ao invés disso pode apanhar apenas o ultimo acrescentando ao seletor `:last`

```js
function addInput(){
    $(".input-files:last").after('<div class="form-group input-files"><input type="file" name="imagem_file[]" class="form-control"></div>');
    //----------------^ aqui
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="form-group input-files">
    <input type="file" name="imagem_file[]" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group input-files">
    <input type="file" name="imagem_file[]" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group input-files">
    <input type="file" name="imagem_file[]" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>

<button onClick="addInput();" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">[+]</button>
```

Confirme este seletor na [referência de seletores do JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/).

Alternativamente podia ter utilizado o selector [`:last-child` de CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child), que iria funcionar na mesma.

Comment: Obrigado, é isso mesmo, deu certo! em 9min aceito a resposta por padrão aqui, e para remover faço o mesmo? Uso o :last com o .remove(); né?

Comment: @EliseuB. Sim, caso queira remover o ultimo `.input-files` que existe

Comment: Fiz o remover e deu certo